# Where can I find an API to read movie budget?

Tags: api, movie

I am looking for an API that would give me movie budget, domestic revenue and first wekeend revenue but I can't find any. Ideas?

Comment: Does it need to be free?

Answer (score 1):

[Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)

Not sure if there is a free api that will get the information you want, but the links on that question might give you some leads.

Comment: The example responses I could find don't display budget.  It might be available for some movies but in general does not seem to be available

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [themoviedb.org](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/methods/Movie.getInfo).

The default response for `Movie.getInfo` displays a `budget` parameter.