# What is a good website to review movies on that provides API access?

Tags: web-services, api, movie, review

I'm updating my personal blog and I would like to start reviewing the movies I watch (an embarrassingly large number...).

Could anyone recommend a good website where I can leave a review of a movie/TV show **that also provides an API** for me to access my own reviews so I can display them on my site.

Thanks,

Comment: You could write some yourself, but in the way you ask the question, I feel that isn't your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find these APIs:

- [Filmaster](http://filmaster.org/display/DEV/API) seems to have what you are looking for.
- [FilmCrave](http://www.filmcrave.com/api.php), although it looks like you would have to pay to use the API for mobile device APPs.
- [NetFlix](http://developer.netflix.com/docs), if you are a subscriber.
- [IMDb](http://www.imdbapi.com/) which seems to be well [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api) although information seems somewhat scarce.

You can also take a look at these APIs although it doesn't look like they provide access to member reviews, they may be what you are looking for:

- [RottenTomatoes](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs)
- [NYTimes](http://developer.nytimes.com/docs/movie_reviews_api)

Comment: Filmaster looks great.  Thanks for the exhaustive list.