# IMDB API to retrieve character information

Tags: api, imdb

Is there an IMDB API to retrieve character information ? Assuming I know the exact name of the character ?

Comment: Try http://mashape.com/apathetic/imdb

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two public, undocumented api's that may change at any time since they are undocumented and unsupported

One of them gives you some json with some relevant information for an actor: http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q={NAME+OF+ACTOR}

As an example: http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=jessica+simpson

More details can be found with this question and this answer in particular [Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api/7744369#7744369)

Comment: Right thanks :) Went through the thread, found it very useful.

Comment: Hello, Do you have an update for this answer? actually doesn´t work