# Scraping IMDB with beautfulsoup in Python; search result then enter link then get year

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, gettext, imdb

I'm trying to scrape IMDB to search for a particular title, enter the first link in the search results, then print the year (and later other info) that the movie was released but I can't seem to figure out what part of the html to put in .find().

The first function works and collects the original url and joins it with the new second part of the url (for the movie page).

Thanks for the help, been stuck on this for days!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin # For joining next page url with base url

search_terms = input("What movie do you want to know about?\n> ").split()

url = "http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=" + '+'.join(search_terms) + '&s=all'

def scrape_find_next_page(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    next_page = soup.find('td', 'result_text').find('a').get('href')

    return next_page


next_page_url = scrape_find_next_page(url)

new_page = urljoin(url, next_page_url)



def scrape_movie_data(next_page_url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    title_year = soup.find('span','titleYear').find('a').get_text()

    return title_year

print(scrape_movie_data(new_page))
```

Comment: use DevTool in Chrome/Firefox to find element (if page doesn't use JavaScript to load data).

Answer (score 2):

First problem: in `scrape_movie_data(next_page_url)` you use `url` instead of `next_page_url` in `requests.get()` so you read wrong page.

```
response = requests.get(next_page_url, headers=headers)
```

Second problem: you have to use `{'id': 'titleYear'}` in `find()`

```
title_year = soup.find('span', {'id': 'titleYear'}).find('a').get_text()
```

Final version:

```
def scrape_movie_data(next_page_url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    response = requests.get(next_page_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    title_year = soup.find('span', {'id': 'titleYear'}).find('a').get_text()

    return title_year
```

---

**EDIT:** check `IMDB API` in Google. Some interesting results

[SO - IMDB API to retrieve character information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216538/imdb-api-to-retrieve-character-information)

[SO - Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api/7744369#7744369)

and you can get results as JSON so you don't have to scrape.

Other portals:

[OMDb API -The Open Movie Database](https://www.omdbapi.com/)

[The Movie DB API](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api)

---

**EDIT:** JSON data

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&tt=on&q={}'
#url = 'http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q={}'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

title = input("Title: ").split()

response = requests.get(url.format(title[0]), headers=headers)

data = response.json()

for x in data['title_popular']: # data['title_approx']:
    print('title:', x['title'])
    print(' year:', x['title_description'][:4])
    print('---')
    print('  id:', x['id'])
    print('name:', x['name'])
    print('        title:', x['title'])
    print('episode_title:', x['episode_title'])
    print('title_description:', x['title_description'])
    print('      description:', x['description'])
    print('------------------------------------')
```

Comment: I add links about API.