# API or any other way to access IMDB TOP 250 list?

Tags: jsp, web-scraping, imdb

I have done extensive research and found that I couldn't find an API. Is there any available API to get the TOP 250 list?

Or another way to get access to the list?

I tried accessing the page HTML and parsing in my JSP backend. But the problem here is that I get only a skeleton, the list loads as AJAX.

Any way of web scraping it?

Any usage Idea would be appreciated...

Comment: Why don't make a request to the endpoint the script calls (make the ajax call)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does IMDB provide an API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)

Comment: The link in my comment above contains the solution.

Comment: but no solution has a way to get the TOP 250 list.. Am specific on the "TOP 250 list"

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to just download the data from the [IMDb alternate interfaces](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces).

The file you want is **ratings.list.gz**.  The Top 250 films are listed in the first section.

Comment: I believe they are updated weekly.  And the top 250 movies would not change very much day to day, anyway.

Comment: I have written a script that converts all the `.list.gz` files to JSON which should make it easier to work with: https://github.com/oxplot/imdb2json

Comment: Mansour: those files are enormous already, and I'd guess JSON is even larger due to the tags for formatting.  What most people do is load them into a relational database for queries.  I have done this for SQL Server and others have written a parser for python/mysql.

Answer (score 2):

Yes now there is a API called the omdbapi

```
http://www.omdbapi.com/
```

Comment: Nice one..! But it has very limited functionality.

Comment: @JayModi I know still its the only one of its type as of I know

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem too and I solved it with some scraping. Here is the Python code:

```
import requests
import re

top250_url = "http://akas.imdb.com/chart/top"


def get_top250():
    r = requests.get(top250_url)
    html = r.text.split("\n")
    result = []
    for line in html:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        m = re.search(r'data-titleid="tt(\d+?)">', line)
        if m:
            _id = m.group(1)
            result.append(_id)
    #
    return result
```

It returns the IMDb IDs of the Top 250 movies. Then, using the [imdbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) package you can ask all the information about a movie, since you have the movie ID.

Answer (score 0):

Available from there:

http://api.myapifilms.com/imdb.do

Get url for it is there: (You'll need a free token)

```
 http://api.myapifilms.com/imdb/top?token=GET A FREE API KEY&format=json&data=0
```

(Not my site)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.theimdbapi.com/
this one is great, i am usng from sometime now