# Python: Extracting numbers from result

Tags: python

I was working on a python script to automatically extract ratings from imdb, only I am unable to extract the numbers from my result.

```
from pattern.web import URL
from pattern.web import plaintext
from pattern.web import decode_utf8
import re

def scrape_imdb(film):
    url = URL (film)
    s=url.download()
    decode_utf8(url.download(s))
    regels=re.compile(('"ratingValue">[0-9].[0-9]'))
    rating= regels.findall(s)
    rating2= rating[0:1]
    rating3= rating2.findall("[0-9"])

    regels2=re.compile ("<title>.*</title>")
    titel=regels2.findall(s)
    print titel, rating2
```

But this gives me an error. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Someone will only be able to resolve this if you post your exact error message too.

Comment: Please for the love of god don't scrape popular websites, its against the terms of service and normally gets you IP banned! Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7744369/462604

Comment: `rating2.findall("[0-9"])` <- The ending quote character is in the wrong spot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote in a comment to another answer:

> I still get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'

So this seems to be your problem. `re.findall` returns a list of matches, so `rating` is a list. When you then do `rating2 = rating[0:1]`, you assign a sublist to `rating2`, so `rating2` itself is a list too (with a single element though). A list does not have a `findall` method so this fails.

What you probably want to do is run another regular expression on the first result in `rating`:

```
rating = regels.findall(s)
rating2 = rating[0] # only get the first element; a string
rating3 = re.findall("[0-9]", rating2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo here:

```
rating3= rating2.findall("[0-9"])
```

It should be:

```
rating3= rating2.findall("[0-9]")
```

Comment: Even when i correct the error, I still get: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'findall'