# API to fetch Celebrity BIO

Tags: api, imdb

Is there any free api to fetch celebrity BIO? I can see that info in `IMDB` but i can't find any `API` there to fetch it.

```
http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/bio
```

Comment: close voters care to comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search gives:

[Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)

and

http://mymovieapi.com/

You can always use an http request and parse the webpage yourself.

You didn't really mention what you're trying to get the Bio from, if from a desktop application you can simply use whatever HTTP library.

If you're looking to use a web request you will have to set up CORS to allow the cross domain call and parse through the bio page. I've done the following with jQuery:

```
var htmlData="";
$.get('http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000216/bio', function(data) { htmlData=data; });
var bio = $(htmlData).find('#tn15content')[0].textContent;
```

Comment: I dint find the answer for my question there and i already seen the links... Thanks...

Comment: See my edit for an answer, you need to give us some more info.

Comment: +1, Thanks for your time with more explanation..