# python string.replace() a string + 12 characters following

Tags: python, string, replace

I am using python to scrape some info off IMDb and am looking to replace a given text + 12 characters that follow it with a blank. Is this possible? Here is an example:

I have the string

```
'<a href="/name/nm2142796/">Santino Rice</a> tells Roxxxy Andrews that she was "like Chewbaca in drag."'
```

And would like to replace the `'<a href="/name/nm2142796/">'` with `''`, but is there a way to do something like:

```
string.replace('<a href="/name/'+12,'')
```

it comes up quite a bit, but the `nm#######` is always different (it is always 7 digits following the nm though).

Comment: What about the `</a>`?

Comment: yea, that's easy though `string.replace('</a>','')` haha

Comment: Did you read the [Conditions of Use](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_article?conditions): **Robots and Screen Scraping**: You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

Comment: ...especially since there's an [API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is strictly what your're asking for:

```
import re
re.sub('<a href="/name/.{9}', '', string)
```

Replaces the string and 9 more characters.

```
re.sub('<a href="/name/[^>]*>',  '', string)
```

would also work, without relying on a number of characters.

But of course it would be better to use a html parse istead of trying to clean html using string manipulation. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for example, or [lxml](http://lxml.de), [htmlparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)... pick one.

Comment: ahh of course, regex. Didn't even pop into my mind for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: would be `{12}` though to include the extra `/">`

Comment: ahh, no way to do it more than once?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep regex out of it, you could do something like this:

```
string.replace('<a href="/name/','')[12:]
```

Or you could replace using a regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'<a href="/name/nm[\d]+/">', '', string)
```

Comment: well, regex isn't too bothersome, but how does `string.replace('<a href="/name/','')[12:]` work? I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Also, see my comment on the answer by mata, is there a way to have regex replace all occurrences?