# top 250 imdb detail php grabber

Tags: php, mysql, imdb

I'm trying to build a personal movie database and i want the data to be fetched from imdb ...
Yes i know there are plenty api and grabber out there but none of them is doing what is need,,,

So far i couldn't come up with a solution to parse http://www.imdb.com/chart/top list and get my data from it...

I've tried to do it by a curl script but no luck !

For e.g:

I want to know if The Godfather: Part II is in top 250 ?if yes  what is the rank...

Comment: There are a few pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## API

I would look into whether or not IMDB have an API available... If they do this will likely be as simple as querying a URL and parsing the data returned with `json_decode`...

## No API available?

### Get the webpage

No need to use CURL a simple `file_get_contents` will do the trick...

### Extract the list

Now you have the web page you then have two options:

1. Parse the web page with a DOM parser (long winded, not necessary)
2. Regex to extract the info you're after (simple, short)

#### Regex

A quick look at the source code of the list shows the list is in the format:

```
<td class="titleColumn">RANK. <a href="/link/to/film" title="Director/Leads" >FILM TITLE</a>
```

*See CAPS for required information*

Now converting this into a regex is simple; just remove the *noise* and replace with (non-greedy) wild cards...

```
<td class="titleColumn">RANK. <a.*?>FILM TITLE</a>
```

Add your capture groups:

```
<td class="titleColumn">(RANK). <a.*?>(FILM TITLE)</a>
```

and that's it...

```
#<td class="titleColumn">(\d+)\. <a.*?>(.*?)</a>#
```

### Example

Using this in practice:

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.imdb.com/chart/top"); //Download the page

preg_match_all('#<td class="titleColumn">(\d+)\. <a.*?>(.*?)</a>#', $page, $matches); //Match ranks and titles

$top250 = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);          //Final array in format RANK=>TITLE
```

Then you can do something like:

```
echo $top250[1];

/**
Output:

The Shawshank Redemption

*/

echo array_search("The Godfather", $top250);

/**
Output:

2

*/
```

You can then use standard `PHP` array functions to do things like search for films.

http://php.net/file_get_contents
http://php.net/preg_match_all
http://php.net/array_combine
http://php.net/array_search

---

### Side note

*Especially* if you use the **No API** method above you might like to think about storing the results locally and only updating every X Hours/Days/Weeks to save load times etc. I assume that you are already planning on doing this (as you said you wanted a personal movie data base... But just thought I'd mention it anyway!