# Regex to parse an imdb page and get the name

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm not very good at regex and looked everywhere i could.
I could use some help to parse this page (http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&groups=oscar_best_picture_winners&sort=year,desc&ref_=nv_ch_osc_3) to get the movies name .
P.S: Could use a dummy regex too.

Comment: you don't want a regex for now.
first, convert your html page in XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

This is *almost* the same problem as your previous question and the answer is the same... Albeit with a modified regex.

```
#<td class="number">(\d+).</td>.*?<a href="/title/tt\d+/">(.*?)</a>#s
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19600974/2573622

---

## Expanded answer

#### About regex

For more information you might want to check out the following link:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Click on *Tutorial* on the top menu bar and there are explanations about just about everything regex.

### Making the regex

Firstly, you have to get the relevant html (for one movie) from the page...

```
<td class="number">RANK.</td>
  <td class="image">
    <a href="/title/tt000000/" title="FILM TITLE (YEAR)"><img src="http://imdb.com/path-to-image.jpg" height="74" width="54" alt="FILM TITLE (YEAR)" title="FILM TITLE (YEAR)"></a>
  </td>
  <td class="title">
    

<span class="wlb_wrapper" data-tconst="tt000000" data-size="small" data-caller-name="search"></span>

    <a href="/title/tt000000/">FILM TITLE</a>
```

You then strip out the noise/changeable info...

```
<td class="number">RANK.</td>.*?<a href="/title/tt\d+/">FILM TITLE</a>
```

Then add your capture groups...

```
<td class="number">(RANK).</td>.*?<a href="/title/tt\d+/">(FILM TITLE)</a>
```

and that's it:

```
 #<td class="number">(\d+).</td>.*?<a href="/title/tt\d+/">(.*?)</a>#s
```

*The `s` modifier after the ending pattern delimiter makes the regex engine make `.` match new lines as well*

### With code

*Same as in previous answer (with modified regex)*

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?count=100&groups=oscar_best_picture_winners&sort=year,desc&ref_=nv_ch_osc_3');

preg_match_all('#<td class="number">(\d+).</td>.*?<a href="/title/tt\d+/">(.*?)</a>#s', $page, $matches);


$filmList = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Then you can do:

```
echo $filmList[1];

/**
Output:

Argo

*/

echo array_search("The Artist", $filmList);

/**
Output:

2

*/
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
http://php.net/file_get_contents
http://php.net/preg_match_all
http://php.net/array_combine
http://php.net/array_search

Comment: Thank's a lot man... Here is another problem , my server is in hetzner and movies name are in German... Any idea??

Comment: No problem. As for your other problem I'm not sure what you mean... Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know _exactly_ how IMDB works out which language to use... However, looking at their help pages: http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?titlelanguagedisplay it suggests that if you prepend `akas` to the url (i.e. `akas.imdb.com/....`) it should show the title in it's original langauge... Which should(?) fix things for most(?) titles. If not, perhaps routing your request through a proxy server in the UK/USA/etc. would do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which backslashes you do/don't need:

```
href=\"\/title\/tt.*height=\"74\" width=\"54\" alt=\"([^"]*)\"
```

useful result is `\1` or `$1`