# How can I extract movie names by regular expression

Tags: java, regex, r

Here are some examples of data:

```
1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
```

I wish to extract the movie names with the year:

```
Toy Story (1995)

GoldenEye (1995)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: either java or R would be fine

Comment: This can be done using a simple `String#split`

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19607783/regex-to-parse-an-imdb-page-and-get-the-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java this can be done relatively easily by using the [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

```
String str = "1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0";
String movieName = str.split("\\|")[1];
```

Comment: Good call - regexes are overkill for this.

Comment: @DavidFaber `split` uses a regex :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is much simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be pipe(`|`)-seperated data, so

```
df <- read.table(sep = "|", text="
1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)|0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995||http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995)|0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0")
```

Then select the second column:

```
df[, 2]
# [1] Toy Story (1995) GoldenEye (1995)
# Levels: GoldenEye (1995) Toy Story (1995)
```