# is there any web service to give me list of movies from IMDb?

Tags: android, web-services, listview, imdb

I need a web service to get all the movies of a particular year which will be passed as parameter to service.

I need it for practice and populate list of movies in android listview.

Please can anyone suggest to me which web service i need to work on?

Sorry if this sounds elementary as I am new to web services and still learning how to consume them!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very interesting discussion on IMDB web apis. You can hit them to get results

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7744369/1123226

AND

Check this - exactly what you need
http://www.omdbapi.com/

Try this omdbapi.com/?t=ca&y=2012&r=XML in browser . Seems either id or title is required. You can iterate on title words from aa to zz.

Since title is required attribute, and minimum requirement is 2 characters in title, you can get all movies if you queried for title between aa and zz, assuming there are no digits and keeping all other params(year=2012) constant. These XML result sets can be appended using simple queries to get all 2012 movies

Comment: I have seen that...but couldnt find how to get all the movie list of a particular year

Comment: Try this http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=ca&y=2012&r=XML in browser . Seems either id or title is required. You can iterate on title words from aa to zz :)

Comment: what do you mean to iterate from aa to zz...aa will give me one movie, bb another movie....zz total 26 movies...well truly saying i did not got the iteration part!!!

Comment: Since title is required attribute, and minimum requirement is 2 characters in title, you can get all movies if you queried for title between aa and zz, assuming there are no digits and keeping all other params(year=2012) constant. These XML result sets can be appended using simple queries to get all 2012 movies.

Answer (score 0):

You can tryout OMDB http://www.omdbapi.com/ they have a simple api