# Delphi Regular Expressions IMDB

Tags: regex, delphi, imdb

I'm trying to port this c# class to Delphi: 
http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb/imdb_asp_csharp.htm

I have allready wirtten the Helper classes e.g MAtchAll etc. and written the code to get the http from a WebPage.

But my problem is this line :

```
ArrayList imdbUrls = matchAll(@"<a href=""(http://www.imdb.com/title/tt\d{7}/)"".*?>.*?</a>", html);
```

Here is my version of MatchAll

```
function MatchAll(const aExpression, aHtml: string; i: Integer = 0): TStringDynArray;
var
  ResultArray: TStringDynArray;
  Match: TMatch;
begin
  SetLength(ResultArray, 0);
  for Match in TRegEx.Matches(aHtml, aExpression, [roMultiLine]) do
  begin
    SetLength(ResultArray, length(ResultArray) + 1);
    ResultArray[length(ResultArray) - 1] := Match.Groups[i].Value.Trim;
  end;

  Result := ResultArray;
end;
```

And my version of GetUrlData

```
function RandomNext(const AFrom, ATo: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Random(ATo - AFrom) + AFrom);
end;

function GetUrlData(const Url: string): string;
var
  Client: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Client := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  // Random IP Address
  Client.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('X-Forwarded-For', Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [Random(255), Random(255), Random(255), Random(255)]));

  // Random User-Agent
  Client.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/' + RandomNext(3, 5) + '.0 (Windows NT ' + RandomNext(3, 5) + '.' + RandomNext(0, 2) + '; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/' +
    RandomNext(3, 5) + '.' + RandomNext(0, 5) + '.' + RandomNext(0, 5));

  Result := Client.Get(Url);
  FreeAndNil(Client);
end;
```

Given this URL : http://www.google.com/search?q=imdb+13%20sins

How do I extract the IMDB url's?

Jens Borrisholt

Comment: escape the dot in this part like `http://www\.imdb\.com/title`

Comment: Thank you for your answer

This did the tick : 
   http://www\.imdb\.com/title/tt\d{7}

Comment: If I were you, I would use [`the IMDB API`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1966503/960757).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This did the tick: `www\.imdb\.com/title/tt\d{7}`