# Parsing Movie title with RegEx

Tags: c#, .net, regex, imdb

I have 3 strings from wich I want to extract the movie title, if posible in one RegularExpression

```
<title>Airplane! (1980)</title>    

<title>&#x22;24&#x22; (2001)</title>    

<title>&#x22;Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.&#x22; The Magical Place (2014)</title>
```

My best shot so far is this one:

```
<title>(&#x22;)?(.*?)(&#x22;)?.*?\((\d{4})\).*?</title>
```

Works fine for "Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D."  and  "24" but not for "Airplane!".

What am I doing wrong?

Even though it might not be clear the regular expression are called within a C# program, and I'm using RegEx

Comment: Airplane close tag is missing `/`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @alphabravo

Comment: he means you sample Airplane title tag should end with `</title>` yours is `< title>` its not your regex, its your sample data

Comment: That's just a typo, makes no difference.  It is so in the real html. Just for the record: I've just edited my question

Comment: Why are you using Regular Expressions? XML is not a regular language. You should be using an XML library. Or if it's HTML, then you should something like the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: It is HTML wich I get from imdb so I can not change the format

Comment: I didn't say you should change the format. I said you should use al library to extract the data. In your case, the HtmlAgilityPack. Regular expressions should *not* be used to extract information from HTML.

Comment: Mason, yes, regex for html is "bad", but in this case, he's just parsing one tag. lets presume he can get that tag reliably.

Comment: You should also use [IMDB's API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api) instead of retrieving HTML. It'll be easier to work with as it returns XML instead of HTML. HTML is not a format for passing data programmatically, it's a markup language for displaying content visually. XML is however a well recognized format for passing data between applications.

Comment: @hometoast I didn't say it was impossible. I said it [shouldn't be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), especially when there's much better options out there.

Comment: This is just a small project for myself. The main purpose is to learn som RegularExpression.

So thankyou for your advices about doing it diffrent, which i really appreciate. But I would also like an answer to my question. WITHIN the scope that RexEx and Html is the only solution in the world.

Comment: Using an HTML parser would still require you to use an RE to parse the single text node data which is 99% of this task

Comment: Frankly, your regex and your test data all check out in regexlib, regexbuddy, and regexhero. I find no error.

Comment: Strange because I am using regexhero. Expression: <title>(&#x22;)?(.*?)(&#x22;)?.*?\((\d{4})\).*?</title> Test data: <title>Airplane! (1980)</title> result two groups: "2: "
"4: 1980"

Comment: @AlexK. Yes, but many of them offer better support for the intricacies of HTML, in the case of malformed HTML. Leave it to the experts-no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I see the police was here, and didn't like my qestion. because they didn't read the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE for start-of-line => opening tag => optional `"` => read until `"` or `(nnnn)`

```
titles = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(titles);

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(titles, 
         @"^\s*<title>\s*\""*(.*?)(\""|\(\d{4}\))", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string name = match.Groups[1].Value;
    }
}
```