# How to get page title in requests

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

What would be the simplest way to get the title of a page in Requests?

```
r = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/')
# ? r.title
Friends (TV Series 1994–2004) - IMDb
```

Comment: If you're doing anything beyond grabbing a single page, [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/doc/) might be very useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need an HTML parser to parse the HTML response and get the `title` tag's text:

Example using [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/')
>>> tree = fromstring(r.content)
>>> tree.findtext('.//title')
u'Friends (TV Series 1994\u20132004) - IMDb'
```

There are certainly other options, like, for example, [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library:

```
>>> import mechanize
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> br.open('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/')
>>> br.title()
'Friends (TV Series 1994\xe2\x80\x932004) - IMDb'
```

What option to choose depends on what are you going to do next: parse the page to get more data, or, may be, you want to interact with it: click buttons, submit forms, follow links etc.

Besides, you may want to use an API provided by `IMDB`, instead of going down to HTML parsing, see:

- [Does IMDB provide an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api)
- [IMDbPY](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/)

Example usage of an `IMDbPY` package:

```
>>> from imdb import IMDb
>>> ia = IMDb()
>>> movie = ia.get_movie('0108778')
>>> movie['title']
u'Friends'
>>> movie['series years']
u'1994-2004'
```

Comment: Simplest and most straight forward answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

You could use beautifulsoup to parse the HTML.

Install it using `pip install beautifulsoup4`

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/')
>>> import bs4
>>> html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> html.title
<title>Friends (TV Series 1994–2004) - IMDb</title>
>>> html.title.text
u'Friends (TV Series 1994\u20132004) - IMDb'
```

Comment: Why there is an `r` present before `requests.get` ?

Answer (score 14):

No need to import other libraries. `requests` has this functionality built-in.

```py
>>> hearders = {'headers':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0'}
>>> n = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/', headers=hearders)
>>> al = n.text
>>> al[al.find('<title>') + 7 : al.find('</title>')]
u'Friends (TV Series 1994\u20132004) - IMDb'
```

**Update after [ZN13's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4023997/zn13) comment**

```py
>>> import re
>>> import requests
>>> n = requests.get('https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html')
>>> al = n.text
>>> d = re.search('<\W*title\W*(.*)</title', al, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> d.group(1)
u'Handling the Keyboard'
```

This will work for all cases, whether extra non-alphabetical characters are present with the `<title>` tag or not.

Comment: This doesn't work if the title tag has a newline in it, for example `<TITLE\n>` (for example with this page: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html)

Comment: The regexp should be `'<\W*title\W*(.*)</title'`. Without the dot, it gives `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 13`.

Answer (score 5):

Pythonic HTML Parsing for Humans.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

print(HTMLSession().get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/').html.find('title', first=True).text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex with lookbehind and lookforward:

```
re.search('(?<=<title>).+?(?=</title>)', mytext, re.DOTALL).group().strip()
```

`re.DOTALL` because title can have a new line character `\n`