# How to scrape websites based on the site's title using python?

Tags: python, http, screen-scraping

I'm working on scraping websites for websites which contain a certain title.
How would I make it, for example, check "example.com/xxxxxxxxxx" where "x" is a random number if it has title 404 or not?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds the title of the page:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def Get_PageTitle(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(req.content)
    title = tree.findtext('.//title')
    return title


url = "http://www.google.com"
title = Get_PageTitle(url)

if "404" in title:
    #title has 404
    print("Title has 404 in it")

else:
    #no 404 in title
    pass
```

Edit:

The above code checks if the title has 404 ***in*** it. If you want to know if the title is 404, use this code:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

def Get_PageTitle(url):
    req = requests.get(url)
    tree = fromstring(req.content)
    title = tree.findtext('.//title')
    return title


url = "http://www.google.com"
title = Get_PageTitle(url)

if "404" is title:
    #title is 404
    print("Title is 404 in it")
    print(title)

else:
    #title is not 404
    pass
```

[How to get page title in requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812470/how-to-get-page-title-in-requests)

Comment: I'm not looking for the website code,i'm looking for the page title

Comment: Ok...this checks the title to see if it has 404 in it...isn't that what you want?