# How can I discover the amount of reviews that was made about movies in a specific year?

Tags: web-services

How can I discover the amount of reviews that was made about movies in a specific year?

I tried to consume the API from IMDB and Rotten Tomatoes, but it isn`t possible to list all the movies from a specific year.

There are any other choice or am I just forgetting something when searching for the API documentation?

Comment: It helps you get more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api

Comment: I saw this post but the main question is how can I select one specific range of movies based on year?

Comment: Normally it searchs like : http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=gravity&y=2014&plot=full&r=xml or by the IMdb ID