# How to get movies list from IMDB server in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios5

I am working with movie database api. I want to get list of movies released, upcoming etc. I didn't find any public apis in google. Please send me any api's you have.

http://99webtools.com/blog/php-get-movie-information-from-imdb/

This is the reference link for imdb and omdb. From this only getting particular movie by passing movie name and year as query sring. But i want all movies suggested, upcoming movies just like IMBD and youtube suggestions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: You can refer these links for getting movies list 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787808/is-there-any-online-free-movie-information-apis

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api][1]

  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api