# Php scraper extract data only the between tags

Tags: php, web-scraping

Trying to a make a scraper for the first need to scrape the data between the `<a>` tags. I have modified the code a little bit to extract the data in between. Here is the code.

```
<?php

  function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); 
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start)); 
    $stop = strpos($data, $end); 
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop); 
    return $data; 
}

function cURL($url) {
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1", 
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    );
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $data; 
}
    $url = "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action"; 
    $results_page = curl($url); 
    $results_page = scrape_between($results_page, "<div id=\"main\">", "<div id=\"sidebar\">"); 
    $separate_results = explode("<td class=\"title\">", $results_page);
    foreach ($separate_results as $separate_result) {
        if ($separate_result != " ") {
        $results_urls[] = "http://www.imdb.com " . scrape_between($separate_result, "<a href=", "a>");
        }
    }
    print_r($results_urls);
?>
```

What I am looking for is to make the data come in a list form of the titles of the movies. What is the proper way to achieve this as I am not quite sure of regex will be used here or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Instead of scraping their site, you should start here: http://www.imdb.com/licensing/ // This question might also be of interest in that regard, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api

Comment: later I'll be using it to compare 2 pages so I was looking for data between the tags only.

Comment: For IMDB specific, you may try: https://github.com/FabianBeiner/PHP-IMDB-Grabber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help.

> It fetches the IMDB movie meta values (ex. image, title and outline) into
>   a PHP array using PHP `DOMDocument` and `curl` [with separate
>   functions for extracting inner HTML contents and attibute values of any
>   tag(by matching id, tag name and class).]:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;

function disguise_curl($url)
{
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $html= curl_exec($curl);
  if($html=== false)
  {
      if($errno = curl_errno($curl)){
      $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
      $html= "cURL error ({$errno}): {$error_message}\n";
      }
  }
  curl_close($curl);

  return $html;
}

function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start);
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));
        $stop = stripos($data, $end); 
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);
        return $data;
    }

function getHTMLByID($id, $html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $node = $dom->getElementById($id);
    if($node) {
        return $dom->saveHTML($node);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

function getHTMLByClass($class, $html, $bring_tag=false){
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $class_arr= array();
    $xpath= new DOMXPath($dom);
    $results = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$class')]");
    if($results->length > 0){
        foreach($results as $tag)
        {
            if($bring_tag===true)
                array_push($class_arr, $tag);
            else
                array_push($class_arr, $dom->saveHTML($tag));
        }
    }    
    return $class_arr;
}

function get_domattr($html, $tag, $attr)
{
    $attr_vals= array();
    if(!empty($html))
    {
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag) as $img)
    array_push($attr_vals, $img->getAttribute($attr));
    }
    return $attr_vals;
}

function getHTMLByTag($tag, $html) {
    $attr_vals= array();
    if(!empty($html))
    {
    global $dom;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom->validateOnParse = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag) as $taghtml)
        array_push($attr_vals, $dom->saveXML($taghtml));
    }
    return $attr_vals;
}

$url= "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action";
$page_html= disguise_curl($url);


$result_html= getHTMLByClass('image', $page_html);

$movie_list= array();
$i=0;
foreach($result_html as $cont_tag)
{
    $img_link= get_domattr($cont_tag, 'img', 'src');
    if((!isset($img_link)) || (empty($img_link)))
        $movie_list[$i]['photo']= 'na';
    else
        $movie_list[$i]['photo']= $img_link[0];

    ++$i;
}

$result_html= getHTMLByClass('title', $page_html);
$link_pre= 'http://imdb.com';

$i=0;
foreach($result_html as $cont_tag)
{
    $mtitle= getHTMLByTag('a', $cont_tag);
    if((!isset($mtitle)) || (empty($mtitle)))
        $movie_list[$i]['title']= 'na';
    else
        $movie_list[$i]['title']= $mtitle[0];

    $mlink= get_domattr($cont_tag, 'a', 'href');
    if((!isset($mlink)) || (empty($mlink)))
        $movie_list[$i]['link']= 'na';
    else
        $movie_list[$i]['link']= $link_pre.''.$mlink[0];


    $moutline= getHTMLByClass('outline', $cont_tag);
    if((!isset($moutline)) || (empty($moutline)))
        $movie_list[$i]['outline']= 'na';
    else
        $movie_list[$i]['outline']= $moutline[0];




    ++$i;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($movie_list);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [photo] => http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjQ0MTgyNjAxMV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjUzMDkyODE@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg
            [title] => Captain America: Civil War
            [link] => http://imdb.com/title/tt3498820/
            [outline] => Political interference in the Avengers' activities causes a rift between former allies Captain America and Iron Man.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [photo] => http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNTE5NzU3MTYzOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTM5NjQxODE@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg
            [title] => Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice
            [link] => http://imdb.com/title/tt2975590/
            [outline] => Fearing the actions of Superman are left unchecked, Batman takes on the man of steel, while the world wrestles with what kind of a hero it really needs. With Batman and Superman fighting each other, a new threat, Doomsday, is created by Lex Luthor. It's up to Superman and Batman to set aside their differences along with Wonder Woman to stop Lex Luthor and Doomsday from destroying Metropolis.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [photo] => http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTY0MDY0NjExN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU3OTYyODE@._V1._SX54_CR0,0,54,74_.jpg
            [title] => na
            [link] => na
            [outline] => na
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you this will help me sort things out for a bit