# Can we integrate IMDB with our tvOS app?

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos, imdb

I have a tvOS app in which I want to show IMDB ratings of a specific movies. Is there any way in which we can integrate IMDB in our tvOS app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api) - it's a good guide for IMDB API

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to write it as comment or answer..

I think you are looking for

https://www.npmjs.com/package/imdb-api