# HTML scraping using Python and Beautiful Soup (from IMDb)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape, imdb

I want to get movie ratings from [this page](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls026667990/?ref_=otl_2&sort=user_rating,desc&st_dt=&mode=detail&page=1) for example and print ratings line by line,
I've extracted names and release year with BS4 but don't know how to handle ratings...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://imdb.com/list/ls097228983/')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')



for div in soup.findAll('h3', attrs={'class':'lister-item-header'}):
    #print(div.find('a')['href'])
    #print("**")
    #print(div)
    year = div.find('span', attrs={'class':'lister-item-year text-muted unbold'})
    year = str(year)
    year = year.replace('<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">', '')
    year = year.replace('</span>', '')
    name = div.find('a').contents[0]
    print(name + ' ' + year)

    >> I want: Solaris (1972) 8.1
```

Comment: Tangential, certainly, have you considered [programmatically accessing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966503/does-imdb-provide-an-api) instead and eliminating these scraping-related headaches...?

Comment: yes but I need this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change `'class':'lister-item-header'` to `'class':'lister-item-content'` parent class to catch the rating.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request


url = urllib.request.urlopen('http://imdb.com/list/ls097228983/')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class':'lister-item-content'}):
    #print(div.find('a')['href'])
    #print("**")
    #print(div)
    year = div.find('span', attrs={'class':'lister-item-year text-muted unbold'})
    year = str(year)
    year = year.replace('<span class="lister-item-year text-muted unbold">', '')
    year = year.replace('</span>', '')
    name = div.find('a').contents[0]
    rating = div.find('span',class_='ipl-rating-star__rating').text
    # print(rating)
    # you could also format string.
    print(f'{name} {year} {rating}'.format(name, year, rating))
    print(name + ' ' + year + " " +rating)
```