# how can get info from IMDB in C#

Tags: c#, api, imdb

i need a IMDB API for get all info from IMDB

now :
Does IMDB provide an API for this, or any third party APIs available?

except http://www.imdbapi.com/ ==>>because no summaries/description ( i need summaries )

pleas help

thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to IMDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100280/connecting-to-imdb)

Comment: any solution about it with full source code sample ?

Answer (score 1):

IMDB API does (now) provide summaries. In fact, it supplies two: a simple plot and a full plot.

Answer (score 0):

If summary is not implement in IMDB API there's nothing you do about it. You have to wait for them to implement.