# sql query using aqua data studio program

Tags: sql

I have executed three tables in my program. They are `MOVIE`, `VIEWER` and `RATING`. Within the `MOVIE` table i have `MovieID, MovieTitle,IMDB_URL` and a couple movie genres. With every MovieTitle there is a date(year only) in it.

I have to list all the movies that have been released in 1982 and sort them in alphabetical order. I DO NOT have a release date field in this.  However i found out the MovieID of movies.

They are 89,214,228,414,423,440,527,629,632,638 and 674) All these MovieID were released in 1982. I came up with a code but it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me out here? What am i doing wrong?

```
SELECT Movietitle 
FROM Movie 
WHERE  MovieID('89','214','228','414','423','440','527','629','632','638','674') 
ORDER BY MovieTitle ASC
```

Comment: so how do you know they are from 1982? where is the date? It sounds like it is built into movietitle??

Comment: your right it is built into the movie title. for an example : star trek: The wrath of Khan (1982)

Comment: ok. correct query added to Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing "in"

```
SELECT Movietitle 
FROM Movie 
WHERE MovieID in
('89','214','228','414','423','440','527','629','632','638','674')
ORDER BY MovieTitle ASC
```

however if the year is in the movie title, you probably want to do something like

```
SELECT MovieTitle
FROM Movie
WHERE MovieTitle like '%(1982)'
ORDER BY MovieTitle ASC
```

edited to show to query by date

Comment: It's a wildcard. So that statement matches anything that ends with (1982). If you use '%(1982)%' it would find anything that has (1982) in it... and '(1982)%' would mean "starts with"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT Movietitle FROM Movie WHERE MovieID in ('89','214','228','414','423','440','527','629','632','638','674') ORDER BY MovieTitle ASC
```

Also, are you storing the IDs as strings?  Seems like you should.  If so, you would remove the quotes '' around the numbers.

Comment: Yes i am. But '%(1982)' looks better so im going to go ahead and use that. Thanks for the help though

Comment: I agree that that's the better solution.  Even better would be to use some sort of API to IMDB, but from the looks of this question, there isn't one.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100280/connecting-to-imdb